# My pkpass file is not working correctly. Believe it is related to fields

Tags: objective-c, passbook

I have triple checked the certificates and it seems my issue may lie in the format being output by the php-passbook library.

Error message via the console when tethered:

```
Dec  6 09:27:33 JOHNs-iPhone MobileSafari[972] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER/6731247236. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
Dec  6 09:27:33 JOHNs-iPhone MobileSafari[972] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.
```

Implementation:

```
    // Create an event ticket
    $pass = new EventTicket($event['Order']['transaction_id'], $event['Event']['EventDetail']['visible_name']);
    $pass->setBackgroundColor('rgb(60, 65, 76)');
    $pass->setLogoText('LOGO');

    // Create pass structure
    $structure = new Structure();

    // Add primary field
    $primary = new Field('event', $event['Event']['EventDetail']['visible_name']);
    $primary->setLabel('Event');
    $structure->addPrimaryField($primary);

    // Add secondary field
    $secondary = new Field('location', 'LOCATION');
    $secondary->setLabel('Location');
    $structure->addSecondaryField($secondary);

    // Add auxiliary field
    $auxiliary = new Field('datetime', '2015-01-27 @10:25');
    $auxiliary->setLabel('Date & Time');
    $structure->addAuxiliaryField($auxiliary);



    // Add icon image
    $icon = new Image(APP . 'webroot' . DS . '/img/logo_growtix_admin_lg.png', 'icon');
    $pass->addImage($icon);

    // Set pass structure
    $pass->setStructure($structure);

    // Add barcode
    $barcode = new Barcode(Barcode::TYPE_QR, $key);
    $pass->setBarcode($barcode);

    // Create pass factory instance
    $factory = new PassFactory('PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER', 'TEAM-IDENTIFIER', 'ORGANIZATION-NAME', APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Passbook/certs/PASS.p12', '', APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Passbook/certs/AppleWWDRCA.pem');
    $factory->setOutputPath(APP . 'webroot/passbook_passes' . DS);
    $factory->package($pass);

    $this->redirect('/passbook_passes/'.$event['Order']['transaction_id'].'.pkpass');
```

And the resulting JSON:

```
    {
"eventTicket": {
    "primaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "event",
            "value": "Event Name",
            "label": "Event"
        }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "location",
            "value": "The Salt Palace",
            "label": "Location"
        }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "datetime",
            "value": "2015-12-08T13:00-08:00",
            "label": "Date & Time"
        }
    ]
},
"serialNumber": "6731247236_5069_1913",
"description": "Test",
"formatVersion": 1,
"barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "test",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
},
"backgroundColor": "rgb(60, 65, 76)",
"logoText": "GrowTix",
"passTypeIdentifier": "PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER",
"teamIdentifier": "TEAM-IDENTIFIER",
"organizationName": "ORGANIZATION-NAME"
}
```

Comment: Are you using PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER and TEAM-IDENTIFIER in your pass?  If so, this will be causing the error message.  You DO have a signing problem.  The teamIdentifier and passTypeIdentifier must match the certificate you used to sign the pass.

Comment: I am going off the sample code here: http://eymengunay.github.io/php-passbook/ - it includes both? I appreciate any help, it hit me that it was an issue after posting since the logs explicitly stated it.. My bad.

Comment: See my answer.  You need to change the values for these two fields to match your certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the `passTypeIdentifier` and `teamIdentifier` keys.

This line in the log shows that you are using 'PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER' as your `passTypeIdentifier` Key.

```
Dec  6 09:27:33 JOHNs-iPhone MobileSafari[972] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass PASS-TYPE-IDENTIFIER/6731247236. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
```

You should be using the certificate Pass Type ID,  E.g. `pass.com.passkit.admin` as your passType Identifier.  This needs to match the Pass Type ID / User ID shown on the certificate.

Your `teamIdentifier` needs to match the Organizational Unit in the certificate.  E.g. `U4LNY2SS5N`.

If you are using a Mac, you can see these details by using the quick preview (space bar) in Finder.

[image]